# Conversion from string to wstring is causing ú to lose encoding

Tags: string, mfc, encoding, wstring

The variable `filepath` which is a `string` contains the value `Música`. I have the following code:

```
wstring fp(filepath.length(), L' ');
copy(filepath.begin(), filepath.end(), fp.begin());
```

`fp` then contains the value `M?sica`. How do I convert `filepath` to `fp` without losing the encoding for the ú character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function MultiByteToWideChar.

Sample code:

```
std::string toStdString(const std::wstring& s, UINT32 codePage)
{
    unsigned int bufferSize = (unsigned int)s.length()+1;
    char* pBuffer = new char[bufferSize];
    memset(pBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
    WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, s.c_str(), (int)s.length(), pBuffer, bufferSize, NULL, NULL);
    std::string retVal = pBuffer;
    delete[] pBuffer;
    return retVal;
}

std::wstring toStdWString(const std::string& s, UINT32 codePage)
{
    unsigned int bufferSize = (unsigned int)s.length()+1;
    WCHAR* pBuffer = new WCHAR[bufferSize];
    memset(pBuffer, 0, bufferSize*sizeof(WCHAR));
    MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, s.c_str(), (int)s.length(), pBuffer, bufferSize);
    std::wstring retVal = pBuffer;
    delete[] pBuffer;
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MFC, you have access to the [ATL String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(VS.80).aspx).

This greatly simplifies the conversion vs. using `MultiByteToWideChar`. Assuming that `filepath` is encoded in your system's default code page, this should do the trick:

```
CA2W wideFilepath(filepath.c_str());
wstring fp(static_cast<const wchar_t*>(wideFilepath));
```

If `filepath` is *not* in your system's default code page (let's say it's in UTF-8), then you can specify the encoding to convert from:

```
CA2W wideFilepath(filepath.c_str(), CP_UTF8);
wstring fp(static_cast<const wchar_t*>(wideFilepath));
```

To convert the other way, from `std::wstring` to `std::string`, you would do this:

```
// Convert from wide (UTF-16) to UTF-8
CW2A utf8Filepath(fp.c_str(), CP_UTF8);
string utf8Fp(static_cast<const char*>(utf8Filepath));

// Or, convert from wide (UTF-16) to your system's default code page.
CW2A narrowFilepath(fp.c_str(), CP_UTF8);
string narrowFp(static_cast<const char*>(narrowFilepath));
```